# What is the meaning of scrollLeftOffset jqgrid setting?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in virtual mode (i.e. paging is being done via a scrollbar). Firstly I had a problem that sometimes when scrolling by large distance (for example, from the start to the middle) no requests  to server were sent and no new data appeared in the grid. But when scrolling by small distance requests were sent and data appeared in the grid. I noticed that the problem can be solved by playing with scrollLeftOffset property, but the problem is I don't actually understand how this property works. I would like to know how to caluculate this property properly, knowing total count of records and page size.

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid, which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). In any way, the implementation of virtual scrolling has many problem especially if you need to support IE too and if you loads the data from the server (and not use `datatype: "local"`). I'd recommend to use standard paging, which easy understand any user and which can be combined with any other jqGrid features.

Answer (score 0):

Basically *scrollLeftOffset*  controll dynamically the appearance of the scroll dialog information when virtual scrolling is enabled and scrollPopUp is set to true

As from the [Guriddo documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options) it has the following meaning:

> Determines the left offset of the box which appear when virtual scroll
>   is enabled and scrollPopUp parameter is set to true. The information
>   does appear when we use the mouse to scroll through the pages. The
>   value of 0% set the box to appear at upper left corner of the grid.
>   See scrollPopUp and scrollTopOffset parameters. Default value : 100%

It is available only in Guriddo jqGrid from version 4.8